# How to automate "remove comments" from public Website

Tags: html, comments, web-testing

Is there a way of getting ride of comments on a published webpage?

I tend to over-comment my HTML code when I am working on it so I can refer back to previous code, or some test changes I made. When I publish the Website publicly, if someone uses something like Chrome-inspect to see the code, they can see all the comments there.

[image: comments shown in chrome inspect mode]

I want those comments hidden when Its public, but stay while I'm editing it.
So my question is, does anyone have a good way to tag/mark comments for removal once published? or some script to strip the comments clean? (And is there a risk to stripping all the comments)

Answer (score 0):

you can change .html on the end of the file to .php all of the html will work the same but put the comments in something like this and they'll be hidden.

```
<?php
 //hidden comment
 //you can't see this
 ?>
```

start each line with // 
i'm not sure what text editor you are using but in sublime text you can select large areas of text and hit ctrl+/ to make them all into a comment while they are in the php tag

```
<?php //comments ?>
```

Comment: Definitely something I'll consider, I'll test it in a little bit. Any Drawback to changing HTML files to PHP?

Comment: No, php and html work hand and hand, but php is a server side language so anything within the <?php put_something here ?> can only be seen by the editor but anything out of the php tag like <button>hello</button><?php something inside > works just like html, plus i always use php instead of html because it allows you more freedom on what you can do.